# When this coend is invariant up to homotopy?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories, enriched-category-theory

It is a follow-up of my question [Calculation of the homotopy colimit of a diagram of spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/q/408787/24563) which was badly formulated.

> Consider a fixed diagram $D:I^{op}\to {\rm Top}$ where ${\rm Top}$ is
> a convenient category for doing algebraic topology. Is there any
> general sufficient condition on $D$ for a colimit of the form
> $\int^{i} X(i)\times D(i)$ to give weakly homotopy equivalent spaces
> by replacing $X:I\to {\rm Top}$ by an objectwise weakly homotopy
> equivalent diagram $Y:I\to {\rm Top}$ ?

I can think of two situations, I believe quite different, where this happens.

1. The first one is $D(i)=|B(i\!\downarrow\! I)^{op}|$ (for interested people, the argument is explained in Dugger and Isaksen's paper https://doi.org/10.1007/s00209-003-0607-y),
2. The second one is when $X$ and $Y$ are enriched functors ($I$ must be enriched as well) and $D=I(-,k)$. Then the coend is equal to $X(k)$ by the enriched Yoneda lemma.

Comment: Perhaps your question is answered here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/390900/enriched-coends-which-preserve-equivalences/390905#390905

Comment: @NiallTaggart Indeed in the second case, $I(-,k)$ is cofibrant for the projective model structure so Case 2 is also related to homotopy theory and not only to enriched category theory.